# Entity Framework Seed not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this on my web.config.

```
<add name="AppDataContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AppDatabase.mdf;Initial Catalog=AppDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Global.asax APplication Start

```
 Database.SetInitializer<AppDataContext>(new AppDataContextInitializer());
```

AppDataContextInitializer.cs

```
public class AppDataContextInitializer : System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<AppDataContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(AppDataContext context)
        {
            #region Seed Modules
            context.ModuleList.Add(new Module() { Id = 1, ModuleName = "Contabilidad", FontAwesomeClass = "ambulance" });
            context.ModuleList.Add(new Module() { Id = 2, ModuleName = "Recursos Humanos", FontAwesomeClass = "heartbeat" });
            context.ModuleList.Add(new Module() { Id = 3, ModuleName = "Inventario", FontAwesomeClass = "medkit" }); 
            #endregion


            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

AppDataContext.cs

```
public class AppDataContext : DbContext
    {

        public AppDataContext(): base("AppDataContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Module> ModuleList { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
```

and the module.cs

```
 public class Module
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ModuleName { get; set; }
        public string FontAwesomeClass { get; set; }
    }
```

However my database is not created, what am I missing?

Update 1, I added this on the global.asax

```
 AppInitializacionHandler.Initialize();
```

I created this class:

```
public class AppInitializacionHandler
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new AppDataContextInitializer()); //if u want to use your initializer
            using (var db = new AppDataContext())
            {
                db.Database.Initialize(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

and the initializer seed is as before

Database is created but no ROWS are added.

Comment: Is your code being hit at all, or do you need to do something to make the database initialise ?

Comment: the global.asax is hit, but the seed is never hit

Comment: Have you tried something like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236716/seed-database-at-application-start-asp-mvc-3-and-ef

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Initializer is never called if you don't access to the DB. If you want to create the DB when the application start call the `Initialize` method in your Global.asax:

```
context.Database.Initialize(true)();
```

### Update 1:

The problem is you are setting the Initializer in a different `Database` instance, try this:

```
using (var db = new AppDataContext())
{
   db.Database.SetInitializer(new AppDataContextInitializer());
   db.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

Or set the Initializer on the `DbContext` constructor:

```
 public AppDataContext()
 {
    Database.SetInitializer(new AppDataContextInitializer());
 }
```

Comment: hey, my DB is created but it doesnt have any rows, it should have 3.